# camera.split_recording does not generate files on-fly

Tags: python, stream, raspberry-pi

I am recording video and want periodically save that video into files. I use split_recording command.
However the issue is that all videos appear on disc only after stop_recording command.

```
camera = PiCamera()
while (True):
    camera.start_recording('1.h264',format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(5)

    for i in range(2, 5):
        camera.split_recording('%d.h264' % i, splitter_port=1)
        camera.wait_recording(2)

#All recording files appear only after belowline
camera.stop_recording()
```

My application is security camera and this means I can run the camera for days and no recorded file will see, only when I stop the recording that recorded files will appear on this.

How I can dump the recordings into the files without stopping the camera recording?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use custom output object, here is snippet from [documentation](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#custom-outputs)

```
import picamera

class MyOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0

    def write(self, s):
        self.size += len(s)

    def flush(self):
        print('%d bytes would have been written' % self.size)

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 60
    camera.start_recording(MyOutput(), format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(10)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

In this case your MyOutput class need to open a file and and define write function in a way that it closes the file. The flush function also should flush.
For example in the constructor of the MyOutput class you could open a file keep file handler as class variable and the in write/flush function correspondingly write to and flush the file handler.

[Edited] Just found a good answer to similar question:
   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/31389

Comment: The problem of this solution is I need to stop_recording, and than start_recording. This will slow the camera. Alre each time I need to create a new name for recordintg